# Android Device Manager can't locate my phone anymore

Tags: android-device-manager, location-services

I have used ADM before and located my phone and also tried to 'ring' the phone and both worked (After a few tries, but it worked).
Now it's not working at all. I have both WiFi and GPS on and I could find my location using 'Maps' and another GPS app called 'OSMAnd'.

I also checked that ADM is selected as 'Device administrator' and that 'Remotely locate this device' is selected in Google settings -> Android Device Manager.